# Fastest way to repeat a list of matrices a different number of times

Tags: python, numpy

I have a list of N matrices, each with the same shape of (dim1,dim2).
I have another list of N integers, stating how many times to repeat each matrix.
What is the fastest way to create a numpy array of each matrix in the matrix list, repeated x times according to to repetition list?

**For example:**

```
mat_a = np.array([[1, 2],[3, 4]]) # mat_a.shape = (2,2)
mat_b = np.array([[5, 6],[7, 8]]) # mat_b.shape = (2,2)
matrices = [mat_a, mat_b]
repeats = [2, 3]  

result = np.array([mat_a, mat_a, mat_b, mat_b, mat_b]) # results.shape = (5, 2, 2)
```

The only way I could think of, was by using a loop, which is very slow:

```
result = np.array([], dtype=float).reshape(0, 2, 2)
for i in range(len(repeats)):
    result = np.vstack((result, np.tile(matrices[i], (repeats[i], 1, 1))))
```

Comment: `np.repeat(matrices, repeats, axis=0)`  gives correct answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the variables 'matrices' and 'repeats' as you defined them above, what you need is:

```
result = np.repeat(matrices, repeats, axis=0)
```

Comment: Thanks, this is over 10 times faster than using the for loop.

Answer (score 2):

***EDIT**: now see Shalom Rochman's much better solution...  I won't remove this one, in case there is still any useful content, but obviously `np.repeat` is the way to go.*

---

---

Does this help?  If matrices is a numpy array:

```
matrices = np.array([mat_a, mat_b])
```

And you have a list `[0, 0, 1, 1, 1]`

```
indices = [i for i, n in enumerate(repeats) for _ in range(n)]
```

then you could index it using:

```
matrices[indices]
```

Which gives:

```
array([[[1, 2],
        [3, 4]],

       [[1, 2],
        [3, 4]],

       [[5, 6],
        [7, 8]],

       [[5, 6],
        [7, 8]],

       [[5, 6],
        [7, 8]]])
```